# how to access the spaced property of objects in array while calling API?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am calling an API GET method in angular and getting the response as we get usually. but the problem is I am getting the object's property with spaces how can I access this and show in the lists in Angular. I am attachig the images here, I want to access the purchase order no. property from here.  Can Anyone help me with this??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can learn more about property accessors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors

```js
const fakeResponse = [{ 'Purchase Order No.': 'Some fake number' }];

//fakeResponse[0].Purchase Order No. is not allowed
//We use the Square brackets property accessor
const extractedPurchaseOrderNumber = fakeResponse[0]['Purchase Order No.'];

console.log(extractedPurchaseOrderNumber);
```

Comment: Create a model class with the appropriate properties that reflect the structure of the response. Then you can use that standard dot property accessors. Please treat this answer as a tutorial. It should not look like this in production code.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how objects are shown, the keys are still strings. use `obj[0]['Purchase Order No.']`